# Basic UIKit (getuikit) accordion doesn't work

Tags: jquery, accordion, getuikit

In my project I'm using UIKit with success (until now). Recently I was trying to use the UIKit accordion for the first time and failed badly.

So I reduced the code to just this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uikit.min.css" />
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/uikit.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="uk-accordion" data-uk-accordion>

    <h3 class="uk-accordion-title">Test 1</h3>
    <div class="uk-accordion-content">Whatever</div>

    <h3 class="uk-accordion-title">Test 2</h3>
    <div class="uk-accordion-content">Everything else</div>

    <h3 class="uk-accordion-title">Test 3</h3>
    <div class="uk-accordion-content">All the rest</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and it doesn't work.

I tried different versions of UIKit and jquery ... no effect.

This example on jsbin (http://jsbin.com/fusapomoze) is also not working

The documentation on https://getuikit.com/docs/accordion.html shows how it should work ...

Answer (score 0):

It was just too easy

The documentation is not very clear about the fact, that you need to add (some) components in the head of your HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uikit.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/components/accordion.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/components/accordion.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... and i find the answer :)

You must load the accordion component in your page.
In your JS Bin example, add, the line : `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/components/accordion.min.js"></script>` under the `uikit.min.js` one.

So it works :)

See also the source code of the doc page you have given, you will find the trick ;-)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Ok you find it before my answer! ;-)